# ActiveRecord Move All Children to Another Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, splat

I have a table with five different has-many relationships to other tables.  Before deleting a record, I need to move all of its children to another record.  To accomplish this I employ the following code:

```
self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.select {|assoc| assoc.macro == :has_many }.each do |assoc|
  target.send(assoc.name) << self.send(assoc.name)
end
```

Basically, this comes down to `target.child-association << self.child-association`.  But this does not work correctly, deleting all the children from "self" and adding a single child to "target" with all fields except the associated field null.  I think this is because "<<" expects a record and I'm passing an array of records.  I see that "<<" also accepts a list of arguments, so I think I need something like `target.send(assoc.name) << *self.send(assoc. name)` (note the splat operator), but I can't figure out a valid syntax for doing this.  So my questions are two:

1. How do you "splat" an arbitrary array for input to "<<"?
2. Is that what is needed to make child reassignment work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here are the answers:

1) target.send(assoc.name).send(:<<, *(self.send(assoc.name)))

2) The original technique is inefficient, generating 'n' SQL Updates, each one updating one child record.  The more efficient technique is `self.send(assoc.name).update_all(parent_id: target.id)`.  It requires guilty knowledge of how the linking is accomplished (in my case and most cases, a single foreign key field) which I suppose could be reflected from the association).

Comment: To complete @jack-r-g's answer to question 2 (6 years later...), guilty knowledge can be avoided by retrieving the foreign key from the reflection: `self.send(assoc.name).update_all(assoc.foreign_key => target.id)`

Comment: Good point, @MichaelBaudino. It still assumes that linkage is via the PK, but that's less of an assumption than foreign key name.